# error of importing a module (stats and gamma) from python in Eclipse+PyDev

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-7, scipy

I need to import a module from python 3.3 on Win7.

In Eclipse++PyDev, I cannot import stats from scipy

```
  from scipy import stats
```

But, I can do it in iPython.

Alos, I have installed ipython and can do it in ipython by

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
```

But, I need to do it in Eclipse where I have added python, numpy and scipy in it.

But, Eclipse tell me that

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
```

error:

```
 Unresolved import: rv_discrete
 Import redefinition: rv_discrete
 Unused import: rv_discrete
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: do you have 2 different versions of python?

Comment: @zhangxaochen, what is 2 diff versions ? thanks

Comment: I guess you may have installed several different versions of python, and eclipse starts with the version which didn't get `scipy` installed.

Comment: He means, did you install two different distributions of Python. For instance Python 2.6 and Python 3.3 or both x86 and amd x64? An easy way to know is to check your C:\ drive and see if there are several Python folders. Then, if so, make sure Eclipse is using the one which has the module installed (check the Lib/site-packages/) folder.

Comment: @Tonio, zhangxaochen, I have installed Python 3.3.5 32 bits, my ipython is 3.3.4 | Anaconda 1.9.1 64 bits. Thanks !

Comment: @Tonio, I haved checked the folder to make sure that only py 3.3 that has the module installed. but, I got the same error. Thanks !